# Запятая и точка с запятой в греческом скорописном письме

Tags: запятые, история, точка-с-запятой, письменность, греческий

Считается, что ***запятая*** и ***точка с запятой*** до XIV века были типичными для **греческого скорописного письма** и южнославянской книжности.
Это уже потом, с конца XIV века ***запятая*** и ***точка с запятой*** входят в русское правописание.

Сохранились ли какие-то письменные источники из этого самого **греческого скорописного письма**, подтверждающие присутствие в них **запятых** и **точек с запятой**?

Comment: Стало быть, нет письменных источников?
Нет.
На каком же основании считается, что запятая и точка с запятой до XIV века были типичными для греческого скорописного письма?